# How to generate a List to the second screen in flutter from a JSON?

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to create a list from the value inside a JSON. I can get the length but not for the data. My main goal is to create a list of items based on their popularity.

```
        child: Row(
            children: [
              ...List.generate(
                "items"[0].length,
                (index) {
                  if (["items"][index].isPopular) {   // here I want to generate a list for the value isPopular
                    return BreakfastCard(breakfast: ('items'[0] as Map<String, dynamic>[index]); // Here I want to call the function from other screen
                  }
```

And when I tried to change the code to this

```
                "items"[0].length,
                (index) {
                  if (["items"][index][isPopular]) { // the error here is *Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.*
                    return BreakfastCard(breakfast: ['items'][0][index]); // the error here is *The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Breakfast'.*
```

The JSON data is like this

```
{ 
    "items":[{
      
      "id": 1,
      "rating": "0.0",
      "images": [
        "assets/images/cilantro.png"
          ],
      "title": "Cilantro and Kale Pesto Toast with a Fried Egg",
      "time": 15,
      "description": "Sliced bread is the perfect blank canvas, ready to be loaded up with virtuous ingredients.",
    " rating": "4.8",
      "isFavorite": false,
      "isPopular": true,
      
    }]
  }
```

Here is my code for the card. In this part, there were no error and it show what I want.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fema/models/Breakfast.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

import '../constants.dart';
import '../size_config.dart';

class BreakfastCard extends StatefulWidget {

    BreakfastCard({
    Key? key,
    this.width = 140,
    this.aspectRetio = 1.02,
    required this.breakfast,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double width, aspectRetio;
  Breakfast breakfast;

  @override
  _BreakfastCardState createState() => _BreakfastCardState();
}
 
class _BreakfastCardState extends State<BreakfastCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        Future<String> _loadloadBreakfastAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/breakfast.json');
  }


Future<BreakfastCard> loadBreakfast() async {
  String jsonAddress = await _loadloadBreakfastAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonAddress);
  // This now updates the breakfast property in the main class.
  widget.breakfast = Breakfast.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  // This return value is thrown away, but this line is necessary to 
  // resolve the Future call that FutureBuilder is waiting on.
  return Future<BreakfastCard>.value();
}


    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: loadBreakfast(),
      builder: (BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot){
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: getProportionateScreenWidth(140),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){},
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1.02,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: kSecondaryColor.withOpacity(0.1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: widget.breakfast.id.toString(),
                      child: Image.asset(widget.breakfast.images[0]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  widget.breakfast.title,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "${widget.breakfast.calories} cal |",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
    
                    Text(
                      "${widget.breakfast.time} min",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(18),
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: kPrimaryColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      onTap: () { widget.breakfast.isFavorite = !widget.breakfast.isFavorite;},
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenWidth(8)),
                        height: getProportionateScreenWidth(28),
                        width: getProportionateScreenWidth(28),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/Heart Icon_2.svg",
                          color: widget.breakfast.isFavorite
                              ? const Color(0xFFFF4848)
                              : const Color(0xFFDBDEE4),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    );
    
  


    
  }
}
```

And my problem is in here. Where the list will be generated. I am new to flutter and I have difficulties to solve the problem. In here I can correctly create a function to fetch the data from the BreakfastCard.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fema/components/breakfast_card.dart';
import 'package:fema/models/Breakfast.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';
import 'section_title.dart';

class Breakfast extends StatelessWidget {
  const Breakfast({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Future<String> _loadloadBreakfastAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/breakfast.json');
  }

Future<Breakfast> loadBreakfast() async {
  String jsonAddress = await _loadloadBreakfastAsset();
  Map<String,dynamic> map = json.decode(jsonAddress);
  List<dynamic> items = map["items"];
  // This return value is thrown away, but this line is necessary to 
  // resolve the Future call that FutureBuilder is waiting on.
  return Future<Breakfast>.value();
}

      return FutureBuilder(
      future: loadBreakfast(),
      builder: (BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>snapshot){
        return Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
              child: SectionTitle(title: "BREAKFAST", press: () {}),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  ...List.generate(
                    items[0].length,
                    (index) {
                      if (items[index].isPopular) {
                        return BreakfastCard(breakfast: );
                      }
                      return const SizedBox
                          .shrink(); // here by default width and height is 0
                    },
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      });
   
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want list that contains only "popular" = true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "items" into a Map first. You are trying to use the String object "items" to populate your list. You want the data from the json to populate it.

Get the data into a usable object first.

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(data);
List<dynamic> items = map["items"];
```

Then you can populate your list from that data.

```
child: Row(
        children: [
          ...List.generate(
            items.length,
            (index) {
              if (items[index].isPopular) {
                return BreakfastCard(breakfast: (items[0])); 
              }
```

Your errors are from trying to use json data improperly as the conditional for an if statement.
The other error is because you are trying to send a String as an argument for a Breakfast object when it needs something else (I don't know what that is. You didn't post what a BreakfastCard class looks like at the time I wrote this.)

Dart and Flutter documentation is very good. Try this out https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: Thank you so much. But still I can't figure out what was wrong with my code. I already edited. I also include the code for the card. I having trouble to solve. I tried what I can but seems none worked.